# How to hide the axis in line chart? I only wanna show the line & markers

Tags: charts, dojo, linechart

How can i show a line chart without the x & y axis (but I need to define the to: and from: values)? my chart output is part of a table where the data is presented in graphic form as line & markers.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is this:

```
chart.addAxis({
   type: "Invisible",
   //Rest of axis config...
});
```

You can then use regular divs below the chart and to the left of the chart to add the to and from values (not quite sure what you want that to look like).